# Как определить язык и если он не английский, то поставить английский?

Tags: python, pyautogui

Всем привет, решил я сделать пару функций с pyautogui, хочу открывать хром, вот код:

```
def chr():
    pg.hotkey("winleft")
    pg.hotkey("shift", "alt")
    pg.typewrite("chrome\n", 0.5)
```

Но 2 строка (смена языка, шифт + альт) не работает, так же я подумал что может уже стоять английский, так вот суть вопроса: Если стоит русский какой нибудь другой, то ставить английский, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 3):

Определение ключа для языка раскладки:

```
import ctypes
user32 = ctypes.WinDLL('user32', use_last_error=True)
curr_window = user32.GetForegroundWindow()
thread_id = user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(curr_window, 0)
klid = user32.GetKeyboardLayout(thread_id)
lid = klid & (2**16 - 1)
lang_hex_key = hex(lid)
```

Ключи и языки:

```
Language - Country/Region       LCID
-----------------------------------------------

Afrikaans - South Africa        0x436
Albanian - Albania          0x041c
Amharic - Ethiopia          0x045e
Arabic - Saudi Arabia           0x401
Arabic - Algeria            0x1401
Arabic - Bahrain            0x3c01
Arabic - Egypt              0x0c01
Arabic - Iraq               0x801
Arabic - Jordan             0x2c01
Arabic - Kuwait             0x3401
Arabic - Lebanon            0x3001
Arabic - Libya              0x1001
Arabic - Morocco            0x1801
Arabic - Oman               0x2001
Arabic - Qatar              0x4001
Arabic - Syria              0x2801
Arabic - Tunisia            0x1c01
Arabic - U.A.E.             0x3801
Arabic - Yemen              0x2401
Armenian - Armenia          0x042b
Assamese                0x044d
Azeri (Cyrillic)            0x082c
Azeri (Latin)               0x042c
Basque                  0x042d
Belarusian              0x423
Bengali (India)             0x445
Bengali (Bangladesh)            0x845
Bosnian (Bosnia/Herzegovina)        0x141A
Bulgarian               0x402
Burmese                 0x455
Catalan                 0x403
Cherokee - United States        0x045c
Chinese - People's Republic of China    0x804
Chinese - Singapore         0x1004
Chinese - Taiwan            0x404
Chinese - Hong Kong SAR         0x0c04
Chinese - Macao SAR         0x1404
Croatian                0x041a
Croatian (Bosnia/Herzegovina)       0x101a
Czech                   0x405
Danish                  0x406
Divehi                  0x465
Dutch - Netherlands         0x413
Dutch - Belgium             0x813
Edo                 0x466
English - United States         0x409
English - United Kingdom        0x809
English - Australia         0x0c09
English - Belize            0x2809
English - Canada            0x1009
English - Caribbean         0x2409
English - Hong Kong SAR         0x3c09
English - India             0x4009
English - Indonesia         0x3809
English - Ireland           0x1809
English - Jamaica           0x2009
English - Malaysia          0x4409
English - New Zealand           0x1409
English - Philippines           0x3409
English - Singapore         0x4809
English - South Africa          0x1c09
English - Trinidad          0x2c09
English - Zimbabwe          0x3009
Estonian                0x425
Faroese                 0x438
Farsi                   0x429
Filipino                0x464
Finnish                 0x040b
French - France             0x040c
French - Belgium            0x080c
French - Cameroon           0x2c0c
French - Canada             0x0c0c
French - Democratic Rep. of Congo   0x240c
French - Cote d'Ivoire          0x300c
French - Haiti              0x3c0c
French - Luxembourg         0x140c
French - Mali               0x340c
French - Monaco             0x180c
French - Morocco            0x380c
French - North Africa           0xe40c
French - Reunion            0x200c
French - Senegal            0x280c
French - Switzerland            0x100c
French - West Indies            0x1c0c
Frisian - Netherlands           0x462
Fulfulde - Nigeria          0x467
FYRO Macedonian             0x042f
Gaelic (Ireland)            0x083c
Gaelic (Scotland)           0x043c
Galician                0x456
Georgian                0x437
German - Germany            0x407
German - Austria            0x0c07
German - Liechtenstein          0x1407
German - Luxembourg         0x1007
German - Switzerland            0x807
Greek                   0x408
Guarani - Paraguay          0x474
Gujarati                0x447
Hausa - Nigeria             0x468
Hawaiian - United States        0x475
Hebrew                  0x040d
Hindi                   0x439
Hungarian               0x040e
Ibibio - Nigeria            0x469
Icelandic               0x040f
Igbo - Nigeria              0x470
Indonesian              0x421
Inuktitut               0x045d
Italian - Italy             0x410
Italian - Switzerland           0x810
Japanese                0x411
Kannada                 0x044b
Kanuri - Nigeria            0x471
Kashmiri                0x860
Kashmiri (Arabic)           0x460
Kazakh                  0x043f
Khmer                   0x453
Konkani                 0x457
Korean                  0x412
Kyrgyz (Cyrillic)           0x440
Lao                 0x454
Latin                   0x476
Latvian                 0x426
Lithuanian              0x427
Malay - Malaysia            0x043e
Malay - Brunei Darussalam       0x083e
Malayalam               0x044c
Maltese                 0x043a
Manipuri                0x458
Maori - New Zealand         0x481
Marathi                 0x044e
Mongolian (Cyrillic)            0x450
Mongolian (Mongolian)           0x850
Nepali                  0x461
Nepali - India              0x861
Norwegian (Bokmål)          0x414
Norwegian (Nynorsk)         0x814
Oriya                   0x448
Oromo                   0x472
Papiamentu              0x479
Pashto                  0x463
Polish                  0x415
Portuguese - Brazil         0x416
Portuguese - Portugal           0x816
Punjabi                 0x446
Punjabi (Pakistan)          0x846
Quecha - Bolivia            0x046B
Quecha - Ecuador            0x086B
Quecha - Peru               0x0C6B
Rhaeto-Romanic              0x417
Romanian                0x418
Romanian - Moldava          0x818
Russian                 0x419
Russian - Moldava           0x819
Sami (Lappish)              0x043b
Sanskrit                0x044f
Sepedi                  0x046c
Serbian (Cyrillic)          0x0c1a
Serbian (Latin)             0x081a
Sindhi - India              0x459
Sindhi - Pakistan           0x859
Sinhalese - Sri Lanka           0x045b
Slovak                  0x041b
Slovenian               0x424
Somali                  0x477
Sorbian                 0x042e
Spanish - Spain (Modern Sort)       0x0c0a
Spanish - Spain (Traditional Sort)  0x040a
Spanish - Argentina         0x2c0a
Spanish - Bolivia           0x400a
Spanish - Chile             0x340a
Spanish - Colombia          0x240a
Spanish - Costa Rica            0x140a
Spanish - Dominican Republic        0x1c0a
Spanish - Ecuador           0x300a
Spanish - El Salvador           0x440a
Spanish - Guatemala         0x100a
Spanish - Honduras          0x480a
Spanish - Latin America         0xe40a
Spanish - Mexico            0x080a
Spanish - Nicaragua         0x4c0a
Spanish - Panama            0x180a
Spanish - Paraguay          0x3c0a
Spanish - Peru              0x280a
Spanish - Puerto Rico           0x500a
Spanish - United States         0x540a
Spanish - Uruguay           0x380a
Spanish - Venezuela         0x200a
Sutu                    0x430
Swahili                 0x441
Swedish                 0x041d
Swedish - Finland           0x081d
Syriac                  0x045a
Tajik                   0x428
Tamazight (Arabic)          0x045f
Tamazight (Latin)           0x085f
Tamil                   0x449
Tatar                   0x444
Telugu                  0x044a
Thai                    0x041e
Tibetan - Bhutan            0x851
Tibetan - People's Republic of China    0x451
Tigrigna - Eritrea          0x873
Tigrigna - Ethiopia         0x473
Tsonga                  0x431
Tswana                  0x432
Turkish                 0x041f
Turkmen                 0x442
Uighur - China              0x480
Ukrainian               0x422
Urdu                    0x420
Urdu - India                0x820
Uzbek (Cyrillic)            0x843
Uzbek (Latin)               0x443
Venda                   0x433
Vietnamese              0x042a
Welsh                   0x452
Xhosa                   0x434
Yi                  0x478
Yiddish                 0x043d
Yoruba                  0x046a
Zulu                    0x435
HID (Human Interface Device)        0x04ff
```

Нажатие клавиши:

```
import keyboard
keyboard.press_and_release('shift, alt')
```

Я уверен что определение языка по ключу мы можете сделать!

Comment: Если полезли в ситайпес, то и поставить язык можно через него